# Progress bar while parsing files

Tags: python, progress-bar

The code below goes to a directory that has xml files, it takes them and parses them into a dataframe.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
import csv
from pathlib import Path


directory = 'C:/Users/xml_files'

with open('try.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
   #◙ writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = ['identify','id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt','Counter', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    xml_files_list = list(map(str,Path(directory).glob('**/*.xml')))
    for xml_file in xml_files_list:
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        p_get = tree.find('.//Phones/Get').text
        p_set = tree.find('.//Phones/Set').text


        start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
        for sn in start_nodes:
            row = defaultdict(str)

            # <<<<< Indentation was wrong here
            for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
                row[k] = v
            for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
                row['Rational'] = rn.text

            for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
                row['Qualify'] = qu.text

            for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
                row['Description_txt'] = ds.text
                row['Description_text_id'] = ds.attrib['text_id']



            for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):
                for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                    if v.startswith("-"):
                        v = v.replace("-","",1)
                    v=v.replace(',', '.')
                    row['SetData_'+ str(k)] = v
                row["Counter"] = counter 
                row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
                row_data[0]=p_get + '_' + p_set
                writer.writerow(row_data)
                row = defaultdict(str)
```

Upon using more data, it is really hard to just wait there and not know how far the parsing into dataframe has been done.

So I went and tried to find a way I can show the progress bar. I ended up finding the following

```
import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(1000)):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    # or other long operations
```

I am having problem implementing the code into my code and finding the range which preferably would be to get the numbers of Xml files in that directory

This library **tqdm** seemed like the easiest one to implement.

Comment: Isn't it `len(xml_files_list)`?

Comment: @jingx, I hope i am not asking for much but can you help me implement

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Isn't `xml_files_list` exactly what you need?

Comment: `for xml_file in tqdm.tqdm(xml_files_list):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
for xml_file in tqdm.tqdm(xml_files_list):
```

it should automatically use `len(xml_files_list)` and it will return `xml_file`.

And you don't need `sleep()`. It was used in documentation only to slow down loop for example.

Comment: where should I put the for loop together with the other parts in the existing parsing code that I have ?

Comment: add `tqdm.tqdm()` to existing `for xml_file in xml_files_list:` and keep it in old place

Comment: I am not sure in which line or where should I put ```for xml_file in tqdm.tqdm(xml_files_list):   ```    inside my code

Comment: find `for xml_file in xml_files_list:` in your code and add `tqdm.tqdm()` in your line to get `for xml_file in tqdm.tqdm(xml_files_list): `. You don't have to move this line. ONLY add `tqdm.tqdm()`, nothing more. BEFOR: `for xml_file in xml_files_list: ` AFTER:  `for xml_file in tqdm.tqdm(xml_files_list):`

Comment: will this have an effect on the speed of the code ?

Comment: `print()` always slow down code - even in C/C++ - so sometimes people print text only every few loops. But I didn't find option in `tqdm.tqdm` for this. You would need use normal `print()` and `enumerate()` and `if loop_number % 10:print(loop_number, end="\r")` - to print every 10 loops. You can use `\r` to move cursor to beginning of line instead of moving to next line.